# Simplify Make file compilation steps

Tags: makefile

So I have these three objects that are produced by make and either the source file extension or the compilation flags are different. I'm trying to find a way to simplify these three lines into one or two lines possibly?

```
# Compilation line 
./bin/version.o: ./src/version.c    
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -DVPROC=$(VPROC) -o $@ $<
./bin/logger.o: ./src/logger.sql    
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
./bin/router.o: ./src/router.c  
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can safely specify `-DVPROC=$(VPROC)` all the time, then those three lines become:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -DVPROC=$(VPROC) -o $@ $<
```

If specifying `-DVPROC=$(VPROC)` is erroneous for `logger` and `router`, you could instead write:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -o $@ $<

version.o: DEFINES=-DVPROC=$(VPROC)
logger.o: logger.sql
```

Here's a complete `Makefile:

```
OBJS = version.o main.o logger.o
VPROC = 1.0
SOME_UNKNOWN_COMMAND = cat

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) -o $@ $<

%.c: %.sql
    $(SOME_UNKNOWN_COMMAND) $< > $@ || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

all: example

example: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o example $(OBJS)

version.o: DEFINES=-DVPROC=\"$(VPROC)\"
logger.o: logger.sql

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

If I run `make` in a directory that contains `version.c`, `main.c`, and `logger.sql`, I see:

```
$ make
cc -c  -DVPROC=\"1.0\" -o version.o version.c
cc -c   -o main.o main.c
cat logger.sql > logger.c || { rm -f logger.c; exit 1; }
cc -c   -o logger.o logger.c
cc -o example version.o main.o logger.o
rm logger.c
```

Run `make` a second time with no changes:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Modify `version.c` and run `make`:

```
$ touch version.c
$ make
cc -c  -DVPROC=\"1.0\" -o version.o version.c
cc -o example version.o main.o logger.o
```

Modify `logger.sql` and run `make`:

```
$ touch logger.sql
$ make
cat logger.sql > logger.c || { rm -f logger.c; exit 1; }
cc -c   -o logger.o logger.c
cc -o example version.o main.o logger.o
rm logger.c
```

Comment: But %.c would not work for logger.sql, would it? Because in the second compilation line, the input is logger.sql not logger.c (logger.sql creates logger.c which in turn creates logger.o - all in the same command in step 2).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that there was a `.sql` filename there. I've updated the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you for the update, unfortunately I think I've miscommunicated. The second line of my compilation statement basically means that the c compiler compiles logger.sql and creates logger.c and then goes onto compile logger.c to create logger.o (both happens in one compile statement) - so the above still doesn't work as touching logger.sql does not compile it? Does that make sense?

Comment: That doesn't substantially change anything: we just add a rule to generate `logger.c` from `logger.sql`. I've updated the example `Makefile`.